# Installation problem zotac zbox en1060

Tags: boot, nvidia, gpu-driver

When i boot from usb and choose any option install or just boot, after that i see only black screen.

I'm running zotac zbox en1060 - https://www.zotac.com/us/product/mini_pcs/magnus-en1060#spec

I tried:
1. usb flash drive on other computers and it works fine;
2. switch from display port to hdmi and it did not help;
3. other distributives did not work too.

I suspect that there is specific GPU (in my case gtx 1060 from zotac) is not standart and does not have drivers for any linux.

So how can i install ubuntu 16.04 on my device?

Comment: Guys i realy nee your help. I bored of winows and wanna try smthng different.

Comment: did you manage to get Ubuntu running on your hardware? I have a similar problem to this as well...

Answer (score 1):

First, install last BIOS :
https://www.zotac.com/dz/files/download/by_product?p_nid=582520&driver_type=238&os=All

In BIOS :

Boot : Pure UEFI

Boot secure :

Attempt Secure Boot : Disabled

Secure Boot Mode : Standard

Save and exit

Boot on usb key, and in Grub, select (not press) "install ubuntu" and press "e" for edit command.
**Add "nomodeset" just between "...quiet splash" and " ---"**
Press "F10" for validate.

Install Ubuntu.

When first start, press "**Echap**" for display Grub (not automatic if only one OS installing)
Select "ubuntu" and press "e" for édit command.
**Add "nomodeset acpi=off" just next "$vt_handoff "**
(acpi=off is maybe not necessary)

"F10" for validate

Next, in Ubuntu, you must install NVIDIA drivers :
**In "softwares & updates" / "drivers optionals", "select "use NVIDIA drivers...". Validate.**

You can install "NVIDIA X server Settings" in "applications ubuntu".

Next : "settings" / "devices (?)" / "displays"... select your screen resolution, frequency...

Reboot.

It's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've met same problem on my EN1070 and solved with follow method:

On boot from USB-stick, after grub menu shown, before select "install Ubuntu", press 'e' to edit kernel command line and add "nomodeset" to the command line, then press F10 to continue. Installation will success with very low resolution display.

However black screen will still happen when booting from the Ubuntu installed, apply the same trick as above, we can enter the system, with ugly low resolution. To fix this, additional 2 steps are needed:

1. edit kernel command line in /etc/default/grub, add `nomodeset` permanently and `sudo update-grub`.
2. Download Nvidia display driver from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx. It's an script to be running in non-graphical mode: reboot and hold "SHIFT" key to activate grub menu, select "Advanced options"->"Recovery mode"->"root", execute `mount -o remount,rw /` then execute the Nvidia driver installer script, after successfully installed, reboot.